# TypeScript: Property 'propertyName' does not exist on type 'T'

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Currently I'm learning TypeScript, and I have an issue: "*Property 'value' does not exist on type 'T'*"

Here's my code:

```
type ParseType = <T>(value: T, opts: any, useRounding: boolean) => number;
const parse: ParseType = function(value, opts: any, useRounding): number {
//...
if (isNumber || value instanceof currency) {
  v = (isNumber ? value : value.value) * precision;
}
//...
```

I will be really grateful for help :)

UPD: I just added new interface `interface Currency {value?: number;}`, made my generic type extend it: `type ParseType = <T extends Currency>(value: T, opts: any, useRounding: boolean) => number;`, and wrote two separate conditions as was suggested in comments.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `currency` always contains a `value` prop? Typescript can't infer this because you are using two nested conditional statements - it could in theory but it's not clever enough. In the inner ternary condition Typescript doesn't know about the fact that `!isNumber` also means `instanceof currency` - this connection is lost. The same happens for `isNumber` - even if you got this boolean by checking whether `value` is a number at some point, this type-infering property won't carry along if you are using it somewhere else in a conditional. For Typescript to infer types, the check has to happen right there in the condition.

Try this (flattening the nested conditions into two separate ones):

```
if (typeof value === 'number') {
  v = value * precision;
} else if (value instanceof currency) {
  v = value.value * precision;
}
```

A condensed example:

```
function abc<R>(v: R) {
  if (typeof v === 'number') {
    // Typescript knows v is a number
  }

  const isNumber = typeof v === 'number';
  if (isNumber) {
    // Typescript knows nothing about v
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help! 2 separate conditions make sense, you are right. 
I did that just like you wrote, but I still getting this error.
I've tried to use optional chaining and hasOwnProperty method, but it didn't help me